# In IAR's Embedded Workbench, how can I integrate errors from a prebuild step into the IDE?

Tags: arm, ide

Because IAR's Embedded Workbench doesn't properly handle dependencies between projects (i.e. building a project that relies on a library doesn't trigger a make on the library first), I've been trying to use the Project option Pre-build Step to call `iarbuild.exe`.

After the inevitable load of experimentation, I now have this (mostly) working via a batch file called `prebuild.bat` that says:

```
"C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.1\common\bin\iarbuild.exe" %1 -make %2 -log all
```

and a prebuild step that says:

```
..\..\prebuild.bat ..\..\BootLib\EWPROJ\BootLib.ewp Debug
```

However, even though this *does* trigger a make of the library project, the errors in the library only appear in the Build Log pane, i.e. they're not highlighted inside the IDE itself (i.e. with the red crosses beside broken lines). If I subsequently rebuild the library directly, the red crosses then appear beside broken lines correctly.

This very nearly makes IAR usable for project dependencies, but still not quite 100%.

- Is there any way I can persuade IAR Embedded Workbench to register errors triggered by `iarbuild.exe` in a pre-build step as if they had been triggered by the IDE itself?
- How does the IAR Embedded Workbench grab errors when it calls `iarbuild.exe`?